# matplotlib.pyplot.hist() attribute error

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am quite new to python and computer science in general, so maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point it out!
I can't figure out what happened to my pyplot histogram function.
Independent of the list it is asked to plot it returns an Attribute Error. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

When running:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


test = [np.random.randn() for i in range(100)]

plt.hist(test)
plt.show()
```

It returns:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-268-b26700f187c9> in <module>()
      5 test = [np.random.randn() for i in range(10**3)]
      6 
----> 7 plt.hist(test)
      8 plt.show()

c:\users\wiepvandertoorn\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in hist(x, bins, range, density, weights,    cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, normed, hold, data, **kwargs)
   3002                       histtype=histtype, align=align, orientation=orientation,
   3003                       rwidth=rwidth, log=log, color=color, label=label,
-> 3004                       stacked=stacked, normed=normed, data=data, **kwargs)
   3005     finally:
   3006         ax._hold = washold

c:\users\wiepvandertoorn\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1708                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1709                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1710             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1711         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1712         if pre_doc is None:

c:\users\wiepvandertoorn\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in hist(***failed resolving arguments***)
   6284                 patch = _barfunc(bins[:-1]+boffset, height, width,
   6285                                  align='center', log=log,
-> 6286                                  color=c, **{bottom_kwarg: bottom})
   6287                 patches.append(patch)
   6288                 if stacked:

c:\users\wiepvandertoorn\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1708                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1709                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1710             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1711         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1712         if pre_doc is None:

c:\users\wiepvandertoorn\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in bar(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2118 
   2119         if self.yaxis is not None:
-> 2120             y = self.convert_yunits(y)
   2121             height = self.convert_yunits(height)
   2122             if yerr is not None:

c:\users\wiepvandertoorn\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in convert_yunits(self, y)
    198         if ax is None or ax.yaxis is None:
    199             return y
--> 200         return ax.yaxis.convert_units(y)
    201 
    202     @property

c:\users\wiepvandertoorn\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in convert_units(self, x)
   1489             return x
   1490 
-> 1491         ret = self.converter.convert(x, self.units, self)
   1492         return ret
   1493 

c:\users\wiepvandertoorn\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py in convert(value, unit, axis)
     41         data as floats
     42         """
---> 43         vmap = dict(zip(axis.unit_data.seq, axis.unit_data.locs))
     44 
     45         if isinstance(value, six.string_types):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seq'
```

Comment: Are you sure you installed everything properly? I just tried the code and it works.

Comment: The data in your use case -- check to see if there is any None values?

Comment: @Fre numpy.random.randn() does not return `None`

Comment: Are you sure that the code from the question is really the complete code and that you run this as a new script or with a fresh kernel? It really looks like it's trying to plot on an already existing axes, which could be explained if there is already a figure open or left-over from previous plots.

Comment: I mean in the real-world use case of @wvandertoorn. Not the `test = [np.random.randn() for i in range(100)]`

Comment: @Fre the error is produced by the random list, so this has nothing to do with other data from the real-world.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I tried the code on both Python 3.6 and Python 2.7 and it works for me.

Comment: @Fre Yes sure, the code that is presented in the question works fine under normal circumstances. Still for OP it apparently produces an error. In order to help we might hence try to find out what is different on their machine or their way of running the code. My point was that since the error is produced by the code above, it is independent on potential None values in some real-world use case.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest the code is run somewhere at the bottom of my notebook, so it might be that there is an already existing axes as you suggested.. Is there a way to close/forget any 'pending' axes without rerunning my whole notebook? It took quite some time to get where I am now, I am working with quite large datasets..

Comment: First, for testing, just open a new fresh notebook with only the 5 lines of code in it. See what happens. Depending on the outcome the debugging would go into completely opposite directions.

Comment: @wvandertoorn well, `plt.plot() `i believe clears your axes

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest works like a charm in a fresh notebook!

Comment: @UpmostScarab unfortunately the error message is still produced, but thanks anyway!

Comment: Great. Are you using the `%matplotlib inline` backend in your initial notebook? If not, you may close all previous figures via `plt.close("all")`. (`plt.plot()` will not clear any axes, so that is of no use here).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thank you very very much! It works again!

Comment: I am experiencing the same error, but I don't get it on matplotlib 2.0.2, only when I upgrade to matplotlib 2.1.0 . I had a working interactive animated plot in 2.0.2, but after the upgrade it won't draw anything and just gives me this error. Will let you know if I figure it out, for now I just downgraded back to 2.0.2 .